# Xamarin.Forms Working with Data

Tags: optimization

I'm looking for the best option to work with a database for a mobile app.  The data that I'm looking to store is articles, posts , sounds (podcasts) and pictures.

I have 0 knowledge  (as to 2023)  about the right way to do it.

Also, is user information (for login) stored in a database?  / Same database?

I tend (primitively) to make a db,  build a Rest API,   and use all this.   While I don't even know if it is fit to store the kind of data I need.

Hope I didn't get you confused.

I'll add a second question to this.

In case     I need a DB on server.  and I'm approaching some hosting company. should I be looking for some kind of system?  let's say 10,000 people approaching the information above.
(Would I want DB with a panel or other other stuff i can't think about?).

Comment: Does your mobile app need to be able to work offline or is it an online only app? The answer to that will drive your technological decisions on database implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all hosting companies will provide a database and some sort of GUI to manage it. Msql or its variant is quite common.

The hosting plans range from cheap to expensive. The chesp ones use shared servers and may not have SSD. So they will be slower. Go with that until you have finished and then change the plan to suit.

Information for your users is stored where you want, normally in a database, recommended encrypted.